# Remove any element from fixed-size array based MinHeap data structure

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, heap

I am using `array based MinHeap` in java. I am trying to create a custom method which can remove any element not only `root` from the heap but couldn't. Below is `MinHeap` code-

```
public class MinHeap {

    /** Fixed-size array based heap representation */
    private int[] h;
    /** Number of nodes in the heap (h) */
    private int n = 0;

    /** Constructs a heap of specified size */
    public MinHeap(final int size) {
        h = new int[size];
    }

    /** Returns (without removing) the smallest (min) element from the heap. */
    public int peek() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Heap is empty!");
        }

        return h[0];
    }

    /** Removes and returns the smallest (min) element from the heap. */
    public int poll() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Heap is empty!");
        }

        final int min = h[0];
        h[0] = h[n - 1];
        if (--n > 0)
            siftDown(0);
        return min;
    }

    /** Checks if the heap is empty. */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return n == 0;
    }

    /** Adds a new element to the heap and sifts up/down accordingly. */
    public void add(final int value) {
        if (n == h.length) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Heap is full!");
        }

        h[n] = value;
        siftUp(n);
        n++;
    }

    /**
     * Sift up to make sure the heap property is not broken. This method is used
     * when a new element is added to the heap and we need to make sure that it
     * is at the right spot.
     */
    private void siftUp(final int index) {
        if (index > 0) {
            final int parent = (index - 1) / 2;
            if (h[parent] > h[index]) {
                swap(parent, index);
                siftUp(parent);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sift down to make sure that the heap property is not broken This method
     * is used when removing the min element, and we need to make sure that the
     * replacing element is at the right spot.
     */
    private void siftDown(int index) {

        final int leftChild = 2 * index + 1;
        final int rightChild = 2 * index + 2;

        // Check if the children are outside the h bounds.
        if (rightChild >= n && leftChild >= n)
            return;

        // Determine the smallest child out of the left and right children.
        final int smallestChild = h[rightChild] > h[leftChild] ? leftChild
                : rightChild;

        if (h[index] > h[smallestChild]) {
            swap(smallestChild, index);
            siftDown(smallestChild);
        }
    }

    /** Helper method for swapping h elements */
    private void swap(int a, int b) {
        int temp = h[a];
        h[a] = h[b];
        h[b] = temp;
    }

/** Returns the size of heap. */    
    public int size() {
        return n;
    }

}
```

How can i design a method to remove any element from this `MinHeap`?

Comment: What problem are you facing?? Getting some output??

Comment: Note: in your `siftDown` method, you're checking `if (rightChild >= n && leftChild >= n)` but if only `leftChild` is smaller than `n`, you're accessing `h[rightChild]` nevertheless.

Comment: @RaviJoshi.. But you are nowhere checking in that code for the existence of - to be removed - value..

Comment: @DanielFischer: So what are the necessary changes i should make in `siftDown` method ?

Comment: @RohitJain: I am not sure about that procedure, that is why i haven't posted unnecessary code here... Let me first know the procedure from all of you...

Comment: @RaviJoshi Fix for `siftDown` included in answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the index of the element to be removed,

```
private void removeAt(int where) {
    // This should never happen, you should ensure to call it only with valid indices
    if (n == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Trying to delete from empty heap");
    if (where >= n) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Informative error message");

    // Now for the working cases
    if (where == n-1) {
        // removing the final leaf, trivial
        --n;
        return;
    }
    // other nodes
    // place last leaf into place where deletion occurs
    h[where] = h[n-1];
    // take note that we have now one element less
    --n;
    // the new node here can be smaller than the previous,
    // so it might be smaller than the parent, therefore sift up
    // if that is the case
    if (where > 0 && h[where] > h[(where-1)/2]) {
        siftUp(where);
    } else if (where < n/2) {
        // Now, if where has a child, the new value could be larger
        // than that of the child, therefore sift down
        siftDown(where);
    }
}
```

The exposed function to remove a specified value (if present) would be

```
public void remove(int value) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (h[i] == value) {
            removeAt(i);
            // assumes that only one value should be removed,
            // even if duplicates are in the heap, otherwise
            // replace the break with --i to continue removing
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Summarising, we can remove a node at a given position by replacing the value with the value of the last leaf (in the cases where the removal is not trivial), and then sifting up or down from the deletion position. (Only one or none sift needs to be done, depending on a comparison with the parent and/or children, if present.)

That works because the heap invariant is satisfied for the parts of the tree above and below the deletion position, so if the new value placed there by the swap is smaller than the parent, sifting up will place it in its proper position above the deletion position. All elements moved are smaller than any element in the children, so the heap invariant is maintained for the part below (and including) the deletion position.
If the new value is larger than one of the direct children, it's basically a removal of the root from the sub-heap topped at the deletion position, so the `siftDown` restores the heap invariant.

The fix for the mentioned flaw in the `siftDown` method is to set `smallestChild` to `leftChild` if `rightChild >= n`:

```
final int smallestChild = (rightChild >= n || h[rightChild] > h[leftChild]) ? leftChild
            : rightChild;
```

Comment: Hey Daniel , the remove method is O(n) time complexity. Can't i have O(logn) in remove? Binary Search will not be possible here as elements are not sorted properly....

Comment: Removal at a known position is O(n), but finding a value can't be better than O(n) in the worst case. If all non-leaves are smaller than the searched value, it could be any of the up to `(n+1)/2` leaves, so you must look at them all (if you don't find it before). You can perhaps reduce the constant factors by using a different searching strategy (if you do a DFS on the tree, you can shortcut when you reach a `node > target`, if your array stores pointers to things with expensive comparison, that'll beat a linear scan, for smallish `int`-arrays not).

Comment: How can i change the same method for `max heap`? In overall, where should i need to make changes?

Comment: The algorithms for max heaps are the same, just whenever you have a comparison between heap values (or between a heap value and a value to be inserted), flip the comparisons, `<` becomes `>` and vice versa.